# Undefined property: stdClass::$jumlah

Tags: php, laravel

I've joined 2 tables (detail_pemesanan and pemesanan) and I want to do some operation with data from detail_pemesanan table, but it doesn't work

This is the join query

```
    $data = DB::table('detail_pemesanan')
        ->join('pemesanan', 'detail_pemesanan.id_pemesanan', '=', 'pemesanan.id_pemesanan')
        ->select('pemesanan.tgl_pesan', DB::raw('SUM(detail_pemesanan.jumlah)'))
        ->groupBy('pemesanan.tgl_pesan')
        ->get();
```

And this is my operation

```
        for ($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) {
        if ($i == 0) {
            $st[$i] = $data[$i]->jumlah;
            $bt[$i] = $data[$i + 1]->jumlah - $data[$i]->jumlah;
            $ftm[$i] = null;
            $pe[$i] = null;
        } else {
            $st[$i] = $alpha * $data[$i]->jumlah + (1 - $alpha) * ($st[$i - 1] + $bt[$i - 1]);
            $bt[$i] = $gamma * ($st[$i] - $st[$i - 1]) + (1 - $gamma) * $bt[$i - 1];
            $ftm[$i] = ($st[$i - 1] + $bt[$i - 1]) * 1;
            $pe[$i] = (($data[$i]->jumlah - $ftm[$i]) / $data[$i]->jumlah) * 100;
        }
        if ($pe[$i] < 0) {
            $pe[$i] = abs($pe[$i]);
        }
    }
```

Any solution? Thanks

Comment: You say "it doesn't work". Can you be more specific? Do you get an error? What did you do to produce the error? Do you get unexpected results? What results are you expecting, and what do you get? Also, I realize it's challenging when you're using a framework, but might it be possible to create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that would help others reproduce the problem you're having?

Comment: Yes i got an error, it says "Undefined property: stdClass::$jumlah"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it isn't fetching `jumlah` column

You may try changing your select clause to this

```
->select('pemesanan.tgl_pesan', DB::raw('SUM(detail_pemesanan.jumlah) as jumlah'))
```

Comment: I've changed it but the it shows Undefined offset: 3

Comment: Are you sure there are more than 2 records? You could change `$i < 6;` to `$i < count($data)` in your loop.